# Is it possible to set a function to only be inlined during a release build?

Tags: attributes, rust, inline, conditional-compilation

Possible example:

```
#[inline(release)]
fn foo() {
    println!("moo");
}
```

If not, is it possible to only include an attribute based on build type or another attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] is it possible to only include an attribute based on build type [...]?

Yes. That's what [`cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#conditional-compilation) is for:

```
#[cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), inline(always))]
#[cfg_attr(debug_assertions, inline(never))]
fn foo() {
    println!("moo")
}
```

This is probably the closest you will get to your goal. Note that inline annotations (even with "always" and "never") can be ignored by the compiler. There are good reasons for that, as you can read below.

---

**However**: what do you want to achieve?

Humans are pretty bad at inlining decisions, while compilers are pretty smart. Even without `#[inline]`, the compiler will inline the function in release mode whenever it's a good idea to do so. And it won't be inlined in debug mode.

If you don't have a very good and special reason to tinker with the inlining yourself, you should not touch it! The compiler will do the right thing in nearly all cases :)

Even [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#inline-attributes) says:

> The compiler automatically inlines functions based on internal heuristics. Incorrectly inlining functions can actually make the program slower, so it should be used with care.

Comment: I started looking at the code for a project and the crash happens in an inlined function. The function is inlined even during debug builds (unless I am building it wrong) I know I could just delete the line to work out the issue but I thought it might be handy to know if it could be conditionally applied.

Comment: Hmm, I still get multiple locations in lldb when using `#[cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), inline)]`

Comment: @NeuralSandwich I changed my code and added a bit explanation. Basically, you can never be sure. The reference says: "`#[inline(never)]` **asks** the compiler to never perform an inline expansion".

Comment: Might as well mention that `#[inline]` (no `always` / `never`) allows a function to be inlined *across crates*, but still up to the compiler for the final decision.

Comment: @NeuralSandwich for the purposes of tracking the problem, why not just force it to not be inlined in all build types?

Comment: I'm not sure about my particular problem, even with `#[inline(never)]` I can still find the symbol in multiple locations. I'm very new to rust so I just did some println! debugging instead of using the debugger. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

@LukasKalbertodt was totally right with the original and current answer, I checked the IR and it does clearly work.